# How to remove shapes in viewport rendering 2d animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

When I am playing the animation in viewport mode I can see these blue and green shapes that show the previous and next keyframe. How can I

I would also like to hide the lines of the stroke coloring that show around the character. How can i remove these?

Both things I want to remove are marked with blue arrows.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to disable onion skin and edit lines from viewport overlays

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)